# How to display push notifications using SignalR in MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am using SignalR in MVC to display information in a basic chat type device in MVC.  This is all working ok but I want to display information from a Json payload that has been deserialized like this:

```
Dim iss As IssueObjectClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of object)(json)
```

The information does not have to being displayed does not just have to be an object it could be a variable as well, for example I could also display this:

```
Dim key = iss.issue.key
```

I have the code for the connection using the chat hub device which is displaying basic information (Message and username).  Is this the way that I should try and display my Json using SignalR.  I know that SignalR is used for real-time web applications but I am unsure on how it could display information that has been fired from a webhook as a Json payload.

This is how I am displaying the messages in the chat hub, but I want to display information that is coming from a webhook unrelated to anything that has been typed on the application.  I want to display information from a HTTP POST from JIRA:

```
var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
$('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName + '</strong>: ' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
$('#discussion').text = encodedMsg;
```

How can I integrate SignalR with Json to display it?

Comment: Did you try to just broadcast your `iss` instance to your clients? It should work and you would get a JS object with the same shape. I do not understand if you are just not sure how to broadcast an instance of an object, or if you don't know how to broadcast to clients at all.

Comment: @Wasp Yes I don't know how to broadcast to clients (it doesn't necessarily have to be as an object as I just need to figure out how to do it) as I have just started learning about signalr recently.

Comment: I could also just broadcast a variable e.g Dim key = "key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty simple thing to do, and a common case with SignalR. In your code where to receive and deserialize your object, you just have to call something like:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YourHub>();
context.Clients.All.broadcastIssue(iss);
```

On your client you'll have to define a handler this way *before you start the connection*:

```
var yourHubProxy = $.connection.yourHub;
yourHubProxy.client.broadcastIssue = function (iss) {
    // ...do your stuff...
};
```

This is very basic code which would need to be better organized, but it should put you on the right track. My advice is you go through the official SignalR documentation, which is extensive and well done, in particular the [guides to the APIs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api).

Comment: would this be correct then:  in the user controller i call the hub like you specified, then in the hub i do this:  Public Sub SendToClient(key As String)
        Clients.All.broadcast(key)
    End Sub , then I know how to display information in the client side so that part is done